# How to find rise/fall time of SPI?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, spi

I want to calculate the frequency of the SPI2 line of the STM32L073 chip. I downloaded the STM32L073 ISB file. I followed these steps while doing the calculations.

1. For example I wanted to look at the PD4 which has the SPI2_MOSI pin.

Signal name in IBS file for PD4 pin is **io8p_sudq_ls_ft**.

[image]

Looking at the model selector, I didn't know which one to choose. Thinking that the "lv" at the end of the signal names is ''low voltage'', so I did not look at them. I chose ''io8p00_sudq_ls_ft_pd'' with SPEED00 PD=40kOhm.

Let's go further and look at the RAMP values ​​of the signal name I've chosen.

[image]

Here, the fastest second to be selected by looking at the max value is 99.59326ns.

2. Now by applying the formula Fmax and critical length can be found.

**(Approximation) -> Fmax = 0.5 / 99.59326 (GHz) = 5 MHz**

Critical length for microstrip => ( 0.25 * Tr * c ) / sqrt of ε

Tr = 99.6ns, c=300mm/ns, ε = 4.6 for microstrip

So **critical length is = 3486mm**... It's almost 350cm... Isn't it a very long track for SPI?

Are all these calculations correct? Please correct me if I know anything wrong.

Comment: The rise/fall time of any pin is mentioned in the datasheet. What you calculate from the rise time is another thing, and yes, even if your calculations were correct, nobody would use a 3 meter SPI bus.

Comment: You are right. The rise/fall time of any pin is mentioned, but these values are max values. Using max rise or fall time is not a good option. So, I tried to find the fastest one. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: You are still looking at the wrong thing. The speed setting 00 is the slowest. With fastest IO pin strength You can have 35 MHz maximum frequency out with 6ns maximum rise/fall time under specific conditions, and of course faster times under better conditions. 6ns approximately equates to 30cm bus before you hit transmission line effects. 30cm is also quite long a bus for SPI. Of course you can slow down the bus to arbitrarily low rise/fall times and frequencies to get very long buses but that is not the point of SPI.

Comment: Is it necessary to memorize the information that the rise/fall time of the SPI is maximum 6ns? In which part of the datasheet can I find this information? Actually, SPI is just one example, I'm going to research other lines by citing SPI as an example. When I look at the IBS file it says that the PD4 pin is 0.6 ns in SPEED11, which means 3cm long. When we think of the maximum, why do we think of 6ns and not 0.6ns? Sorry for asking so many questions but I'm trying to find out exactly.

Comment: No, not necessary to memorize, why it would be? And the rise/fall time is not SPI specific, it is for all IO pins. It in the datasheet part which describes IO pin characteristics. The datasheet describes scenario with given load and it guarantees it will be max 6ns so it can be much faster like 0.6ns without any load so it still is max 6ns.